# How to get webpage with javascript using aiohttp?

Tags: javascript, python, aiohttp

I would like to use aiohttp to get webpages.

However, the webpages use javascript to render the content.

I use asynchronous io but cannot get the values I want.

What should I do?

Thank you very much.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import aiofiles
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import asyncio

async def get_info(url, session):
    res = await session.request(method="GET", url=url)
    html = await res.text(encoding='GB18030', errors = 'replace')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    return soup.find('div', {'id': 'divResult'})

async def main_get_info(urls):
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=60)
    async with ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
        tasks = [get_info(url, session) for url in urls]
        result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    estimation_url = ['https://land.3fang.com/LandAssessment/7b6f9d07-dd86-4f8e-8832-7833421e57d6.html', 'https://land.3fang.com/LandAssessment/b6d8b2c8-bd4f-4bd4-9d22-ca49a7a2dc1f.html']
    result = loop.run_until_complete(main_get_info(estimation_url))
```

The result obtained is

```
print(pd.read_html(str(result[0]))[0])
                   0                 1
0  建设用地面积：6209平方米     所在城市：山西省 长治市    
1  规划建筑面积：21730平方米    土地评估楼面价：-- 元/平方米
2  容积率：大于1并且小于或等于3.5  土地评估总价：-- 万元    
3  规划用途：住宅用地          推出楼面价：65.35元/平方米
```

However, the correct result should be

```
                   0                     1
0  建设用地面积：6209平方米     所在城市：山西省 长治市        
1  规划建筑面积：21730平方米    土地评估楼面价：867.61 元/平方米
2  容积率：大于1并且小于或等于3.5  土地评估总价：1885.32 万元   
3  规划用途：住宅用地          推出楼面价：65.35元/平方米
```

Comment: This is an extremely odd jumble of Python and JavaScript to me.

Comment: This code cannot give the content generated by javascript. How to modify it?

Comment: Did you look at all the requests being made when you load the website? I am going to guess you need to find the request that actual contains the data you want.